# Notepad++ how to set a different text color for text inside double quotes for User defined language

Tags: notepad++

I am creating a user defined language. And I setup most of it. But, How do I set a color for the text/string which is inside a pair double quotes?

Example: "Hello" -> want the Hello string/text to be in green color.

Answer (score 3):

- You can browse to `User Defined Languages` settings.
- Go to `Operators & Delimiters`.
- Select in Operators style. Set `Open` and `Close` delimiters.
- Select 'Stylers' to pick your choice of colors.
- `Fore ground Color` would allow you to change the Text color.

[image: How to Set Colors for Text in Quotes]

[image]